# How to make SpriteSpin responsive?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Site i am working on is made with twitter bootstrap and is fully responsive. I have successfully made SpriteSpin to work with my site but there is a problem, i can't make it responsive as rest of my site because it adds inline css to div where the image is.

JS looks like this:

First it calls images:

```
$(function(){
  var frames = [
      "folder/image.jpg",
      (other images)
    ];
```

Then this:

```
 $("#mali").spritespin({
    width     : 960,
    height    : 540,
    (other code)
  });
```

How can i change this fixed width and height and put there css class or w/h to 100% so that is responsive.

I already tried to add css class to container with this but no success:

```
$( "div" ).addClass( "myClass" );
```

I believe the problem here is that the script somehow adds inline css

```
<div class="spritespin spritespin-instance" unselectable="on" style="overflow: hidden; position: relative; width: 480px; height: 327px;">
```

You can see it on official SpriteSpin website (link below) when using inspect element on Bicycle image.

Help me fix this issue or suggest me other 360 image sprite spin solution that is responsive and works on mobile touch.

SpriteSpin: http://spritespin.ginie.eu/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override CSS by adding !important after your own CSS directives.
In it's simplest form:

```
background: red            !important;
```

If you have inline style attributes in HTML:

```
<div style="background: red;">
    The inline styles for this div should make it red.
</div>
```

you can try this CSS:

```
div[style] {
   background: yellow !important;
}
```

But it's not really good practice to rely on it in production code. More info: 
http://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/, 
http://css-tricks.com/override-inline-styles-with-css/

Comment: I dont think that will work.

If i have:

`<div class="sprite" style="background: yellow;"></div>` 

i don't think i can add css, even with !important because of that css markup in style="", it overwrites everything that i put in css file, even !important.

But you gave me an idea and i found my answer here: http://css-tricks.com/override-inline-styles-with-css/

Comment: Cool! I didn't know you could use it like that! I have updated my answer to reflect this, for the benefit of others.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post but I ran into this same problem today. Basically all you need to do is set a media query at each screen size in your css to resize the container and the images will respond since their widths and heights are already set at 100%.

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 100px) and (max-width: 767px) {
.spritespin, .spritespin-instance {
  width:383px !important;
  height:300px !important;
}

}
```

Comment: Still wont work because spritespin is giving these elements some inline css with javascript that cant be overwritten, not even with !important. Solution is to use class or element name and combine it with [style] to change the inline styling and !important.

Answer (score 0):

It's great to use it with bootstrap solution for responsive embed objects

```js
var $container = $(".images3d-container")
if ($container.length && $.fn.spritespin != undefined) {

  var source = []
  $container.find(".images").find('img').each(function () {
    source.push($(this).attr('src'))
  })

  $container.find(".view").spritespin({
    source: source,
    animate: false,
    renderer: "image",
    width   : 450,  //  width in pixels of the window/frame
    height  : 450  // height in pixels of the window/frame,
  })

}
```

```css
.images3d-container .images {
    display: none;
}

.images3d-container .view {
    width: 100%!important; /* here it is */
    height: 0 !important;
    padding-bottom: 100%;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    margin-bottom: 20px;

}
```

```html
<section class="images3d-container">
   <div class="view"></div>
   <ol class="images">

     <li><img src="/img/1.jpg"></li>
     
     <li><img src="/img/2.jpg"></li>
     
     <li><img src="/img/3.jpg"></li>
     
     <li><img src="/img/4.jpg"></li>
   </ol>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old, but for people that happen to look for an answer: the plugin now has a setting for this. Just add `responsive: true`, and set the width of the *SpriteSpin*. See [the official demo](http://spritespin.ginie.eu/samples/#/basics-responsive).